# Issue with Domain Redirection to Another Application on OVH Dedicated Server

Tags: cross-domain, vtiger, ovh, dedicated-server

I have a dedicated server at OVH on which I have installed the open source version of Vtiger, which is a CRM for my company. I am also developing another application on the same server and I want to redirect another domain name to this application.

However, when I try to redirect my domain to the other web application, it shows an error stating that my site does not allow redirection.

Can someone help me ensure that my domain name redirects correctly to my other web application?

Thank you.

I have tried modifying the virtual hosts in the Apache configuration files:

/etc/apache2/sites-available:

And the vtigercrm.conf file contains the following:

i can't send the code i've discord or other things for contact me
Diarapak#7575

Comment: Your code sections are empty, config files are not displayed. Add them so we can try to help.